# Oracle ODAC 12c Release 3 32-bit beta supports EF 6.x?

Tags: entity-framework, odp.net

I have Windows  8.1 64-bit with Visual Studio 2013.  I've installed the latest Oracle ODAC 12c Release 3 32-bit beta which claims to supports EF 6.  When I add the ADO.NET Entity Framework to my project and choose my Oracle data connection, it doesn't allow me to select the Entity Framework 6.0 version.  It has Entity Framework 5.x selected and version 6.x is greyed out.  It says 'An Entity Framework database provider compatible with the latest version of the Entity Framework could not be found for your data connection'.  Why is that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I did the following to make it work :-

First Installing ODAC 12c Release 3 which includes support for Entity Framework 6 Code First and Code First Migrations; NuGet, .NET Framework 4.5.2; and ODP.NET, Managed Driver XML DB. As per

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/whatsnew/index.html

Adding two references , to my project references and they are :

Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll

Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.dll

Installing EF6.1.1 using NuGet by running the following command in Package Manager Console( you can enter it by Tools->NuGet Package Manager -> Package Manager Console):

```
Install-Package EntityFramework -Version 6.1.1
```

And modify your web.config or web.config to use Oracle.ManagedDataAccess , by adding Provider and a valid connection string eg :

```
 <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <section name="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" type="OracleInternal.Common.ODPMSectionHandler, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  </configSections>
  <entityFramework>
    <contexts>
      <context type="App.Context.Default, App.Context">
        <databaseInitializer type="MyProject.Context.Config.ContextInitializer, MyProject.Context" />
      </context>
    </contexts>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.EFOracleProviderServices, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework, Version=6.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Default" providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" connectionString="DATA SOURCE=XE;USER ID=User" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Rebuild your Application  as x86, and start using EF6 , you can check if it works by adding a model using ADO.Net Entity Model using Code First

Comment: The key for me was that Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework nuget package installs Entity Framework Version 6.0.0, which is out of date.

So just running:

Update-Package EntityFramework

fixed the issue.

Comment: The key for me was to rebuild it before launching the wizard.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install from this file: ODAC121010Beta2_32bit.zip and then choose to install Oracle Developer Tools?

It is the only file on that page that includes the Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio which must be updated for design time EF work.

Answer (score 0):

set Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.dll Specific version to True and rebuild your app. And then try adding ADO.NET Entity wizard again