# ASP.NET MVC 5, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess and SQL DB

Tags: sql-server, oracle, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I would like to use a SQL Server database for identity but work with data (crud) in an Oracle database.

I can connect to Oracle fine using the `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess` package. Can anyone guide me as to how to set up the `DbContext` / whatever?

I have set up this in web config:

```
<connectionStrings>  
    <add name="SQLServerConnect" 
         connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-MVC-Oracle-HR-Test-20150514042443.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-MVC-Oracle-HR-Test-20150514042443;Integrated Security=True" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="Oracle" 
         connectionString="Data Source=v-oratesting/syscntrl;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=MYUSERID;Password=MYPASSWORD;" 
         providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client"/>
</connectionStrings>
<appSettings>
    ...
    <add key="DefaultConnection" value="Oracle" />
    <add key="SqlServerConnection" value="SQLServerConnect" />
</appSettings>
```

and

```
public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("SqlServerConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
{
}
```

in my `identityModels.cs`. So far this creates a user account in the SQL Server database, how do I set things up to use the Oracle connection for other data models and controllers please?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26661589/oracle-odac-12c-release-3-32-bit-beta-supports-ef-6-x/27670780?iemail=1&noredirect=1#27670780

Comment: Thanks Steve but that only talks about a single connection. I would like SQL for identity( as above) and oracle for CRUD on an existing Oracle table.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this works:Connection strings

```
   <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\MVC-Oracle-Test-20150519031928.mdf;Initial Catalog=MVC-Oracle-Test-20150519031928;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="OracleDbContextConnection" providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" connectionString="User Id=xxx;Password=xxxx;Data Source=v-oratest/xxxxxx" />
```

identitymodels.cs:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}}
```